# How do I make a Lazy List in an Eager Language?

Tags: list, functional-programming, scheme, lazy-evaluation, operator-precedence

I wanted to make a lazy list in Scheme. This is what I have so far.

```
;; Constructor for Pairs
(define (cons-stream a b)
  (cons a (λ() b)))

;; Selectors
(define (car-stream a-stream)
  (car a-stream))

(define (cdr-stream a-stream)
  ((cdr a-stream)))

;; Lazy List using the pairs
(define (lazy-list from)
  (cons-stream from (lazy-list (+ from 1))))

;; Take function
(define (take a-lazy-list number)
  (define (take-helper i )
    (if(= i number)
       empty
       (cons (car a-lazy-list) (take-helper (+ i 1)))))
  (take-helper 0))
```

The problem with the lazy-list is that Scheme evaluates the  inner expression (lazy-list (+ from 1)) first causing the procedure to go into an infinite recursion.

Is there a way to make the con-stream take this inner expression without any evaluation?

Comment: Darn, now I want to learn Scheme, too :-D

Comment: Its not scheme, but this page has an implementation of a lazy list in F#: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Caching#Lazy_Values

Comment: I didn't see the homework tag.  Is this an academic exercise, learning exercise, or for use in a larger project?  What's wrong with SRFI-40 or SRFI-41?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use a macro.  I'm no scheme expert (especially not on macros), but maybe this snippet can serve as inspiration:

```
(define-syntax pointer-to
   (syntax-rules ()
    ((pointer-to var)
     (make-pointer
      (lambda () var) ; the "pointer dereference" operation
      (lambda (value) (set! var value)))))) ; "pointer write"
```

It's used as follows:

```
(define x 1)
(define px (pointer-to x))
(pointer-set! px 2) ; this (in some sense) becomes `(set! x 2)'
```

So maybe you want something like

```
(define-syntax lazy-cons
 (syntax-rules ()
  ((lazy-cons head lazytail)
   (cons head (lambda () lazytail)))))
```

But I'm not sure.  Have a look at `define-syntax`.

Comment: Wow. That worked. But could you comment on your code. I dont know how and when to use a macro.

Comment: I'll try, to the best of my ability.

"(define-syntax NAME (syntax-rules () ((NAME ARG1 ARG2 ...) SOME_EXPRESSION))))" means: whenever the parser sees (NAME ARG1 ARG2 ...) it replaces it with SOME_EXPRESSION, doing argument substitution in SOME_EXPRESSION.

In the case of lazy-cons, it rewrites (lazy-cons 1 (list 1 2)) to (cons 1 (lambda () (list 1 2))).  Note that head took the "value" 1 (really, the syntax tree 1) and was inserted into the cons; and lazytail had the "value" (list 1 2) and was... "inserted into" the call to cons.

It's somewhat similar to macros in C and C++, except better :)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to go the macro route, you could always just abandon `cons-stream` and rewrite `lazy-list` as follows:

```
(define (lazy-list from)
  (cons from (λ() (lazy-list (+ from 1)))))
```

This is probably the easiest, most pragmatic solution, but it's only good for making lazy lists of incrementing numbers. You could generalize this by passing in a function that will generate successive elements of the list when called:

```
(define (lazy-list-gen generator)
  (cons (generator)
        (λ() (lazy-list-gen generator))))

(define (lazy-list from)
  (lazy-list-gen
   (λ()
     (let ((ret from))
       (set! from (+ from 1))
       ret))))
```

This works pretty well:

```
> (define x (lazy-list 1))
> (car-stream x)
1
> (car-stream (cdr-stream x))
2
```

But there's a bug in the code:

```
... continuing from above ...
> (car-stream (cdr-stream x))
3
```

This error happens because the call to `cdr-stream` calls `generator` again. We can solve this by caching the return value of the lambda:

```
(define (lazy-list-gen generator)
  (cons (generator)
        (let ((gen-cache #f))
          (λ()
            (cond ((not gen-cache)
                   (set! gen-cache (lazy-list-gen generator))))
            gen-cache))))
```

Now it works as it should:

```
> (define x (lazy-list 1))
> (car-stream x)
1
> (car-stream (cdr-stream x))
2
> (car-stream (cdr-stream x))
2
> (car-stream (cdr-stream (cdr-stream x)))
3
> (car-stream (cdr-stream x))
2
```

Answer (score 2):

A lazy list in Scheme is known as a *stream*. [Here's the standard introduction.](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-24.html#%_sec_3.5)

Comment: Yes. If you look at my program, I am trying to make a stream.

Comment: You should be aware that SICP streams aren't fully lazy (the head of the stream is strict) which can cause problems in some situations. SRFI-41, mentioned in another answer, provides fully lazy streams in all situations.

Answer (score 1):

You should really look at [SRFI-41](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-41/srfi-41.html)

In particular, lazy streams created by recursive functions will leak memory badly in an eager language, *unless* you specifically avoid it.  To do so, you need to make recursive functions lazy also, not eager.  This means that your laziness implementation needs to be [SRFI-45](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-45/srfi-45.html), which exports delay, force, *and* lazy.  Functions that build streams recursively must wrap their bodies in lazy.